# Handling images upload while in other form

Tags: image, node.js, file-upload, express

Ok, there is a lot of tutorials on the net, how to upload images to express.js servers. But I couldn't find how to upload images while doing other things, e.g:

there is a form, in which I would like to create article. Users fill it with title, some content... after that, he have to upload images. I would like to give him ability to see thumbnails of those images before he create this article. Of course I can just push them through ajax post with jquery, and put them on the screen with javascript, but: when I upload them on to the server, and user closes browser before finishing creating this article, I still have does images on my server, even though no one will use them.

I'm sorry, I couldn't think of simpler explanation of what I want.

So how to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload image to a temporary folder first and  move that image to desired location while actually saving article.

Set up a cron to cleanup the temp folder.